# Error when parsing DOMDocument with PHP

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domdocument, php-extension

We are upgrading our Software to PHP 7.2.3 and I have the following code snippet which worked fine in previous versions:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>".($_POST['reportForm_structure'])."</body></html>");

$root = $doc->documentElement->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild;
file_put_contents('D:\testoutput.txt', print_r($root ,true));

foreach($root->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeName == "ul") {
            foreach($child->childNodes as $ulChild) {
                $this->loadNodes($ulChild, $this->report);
            }
        }           
    }
```

The `file_put_contents`is just for error research.

I get the following error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. The message refers to line of code where the first foreach loop is. So the data structure is not initialized correctly. I can see that the conversion from HTML to DOMDocument does not work properly anymore.  When I check the output of `file_put_contents` I can see that `$root` is a *DOMText* object instead of a *DOMElement* object but **why?** When pass the argument of `loadHTML`directly to `file_put_contents`,

```
file_put_contents('D:\testoutput.txt', print_r("<html><body>".($_POST['reportForm_structure'])."</body></html>", true);
```

the output looks like proper HTML, so that's why I am confused that I does not work anymore.

```
<html><body><ul class="ltr">
<li class="open last" id="root" rel="root">
    <a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>HeaderText</a>
<ul><li class="open last" id="id1" rel="header"><a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Test123</a>
<ul><li class="open leaf last" id="id2" rel="header"><a class="clicked" href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Test456</a></li></ul></li></ul></li>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue. Did I miss something in the configuration here?

Comment: why don't you use $root = $dom->getElementById("root"); to get the element with the root id?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the DOMText node with the code you show. But my guess is that you are preserving whitespace and then fetch the whitespace node between the ul element and the li element.

```
                            v-------- whitespace node
<html><body><ul class="ltr">
<li class="open last" id="root" rel="root">
```

In any case, if you want the element with the ID "root", use a more precise query, e.g. use

```
$root = $doc->getElementById("root");
```

You can also you can set `$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false` but it's better to query for the node by ID instead of traversing down three children and assuming it's that node.

Comment: I up this. My bet is there is some whitespace that was just ignored before. There is an option to loadHtml to ignore empty nodes i.e.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used `$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` option now but it still does not work. Also, the selection of the root element (`html` node) works fine as well as the selection the `body` node but from there downwards nothing works. Looks `loadHtml` interprets this as plain text.

Comment: @NewToSoap [I cannot reproduce your issue](https://3v4l.org/1CHkF). There might be an issue with your POST data not being what you think it is. Consider var_dump'ing the POST data and adding it to your question. Or provide the output of $doc->saveHtml();

Comment: @Gordon, thanks for the effort. The `$doc->saveHtml()` output:    `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><ul class="ltr">
 <li class="open last" id="root" rel="root">
  <a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>TestHeader</a>
 <ul><li class="open last" id="id1" rel="header"><a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Test123</a><ul><li class="open leaf last" id="id2" rel="header"><a class="clicked" href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>New Heading</a></li></ul></li></ul></li>
</ul></body></html>`

Comment: @NewToSoap still no reproduce https://3v4l.org/MhcZ6. Please do `echo $doc->saveHtml($root)` to see what that node is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gordon and @DarsVaeda for pointing me in the right direction. `DOMDocument` interprets carriage returns and tabs as text nodes. I had to remove those to make it work again. Changed

```
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>".$_POST['reportForm_structure']."</body></html>");
```

to

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();       
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $_POST['reportForm_structure']));
$string = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $string );       
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>".$string."</body></html>");
```

Comment: I dont understand why you would be doing this instead of $root = $doc->getElementById("root"); which is much more precise.

Comment: @Gordon I agree with you. About the why you have to ask this my already retired predecessor who implemented this. I have no clue why he used `firstChild` instead of `getElementById`.

Comment: I am not really interested why your predecessor did it this with `firstChild`. I blame inexperience. I am more interested in why *you* decided to change the code like you did now instead of using the `getElementById` which you agree is better to use ;)

Comment: Who said I did not use `getElementById` after `loadHTML` works properly now? ;)

Comment: But if you use getElementById, you don't need to strip away the carriage returns and tabs.